# Error on building gcc cross compiler toolchain

Tags: linux, compiling, gcc, glibc, cross-compilation

I'm following [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source) guide to build a linux system for learning experience
On the the guide at the section titled **GCC (Static)**, I'm having an error, on running the command `

```
$ ln -vs libgcc.a `${LJOS_TARGET}-gcc -print-libgcc-file-name |
  ↪sed 's/libgcc/&_eh/'`


No command '-gcc' found, did you mean:
Command 'gcc' from package 'gcc' (main)
Command 'cgcc' from package 'sparse' (universe)
-gcc: command not found
'./libgcc.a' -> 'libgcc.a'
```

I ignored it and continued to the title **Glibc**, but I'm getting another error following this command

```
BUILD_CC="gcc" CC="${LJOS_TARGET}-gcc" \
AR="${LJOS_TARGET}-ar" \
RANLIB="${LJOS_TARGET}-ranlib" CFLAGS="-O2" \
../glibc-2.27/configure --prefix=/usr \
--host=${LJOS_TARGET} --build=${LJOS_HOST} \
--disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-tls \
--enable-kernel=2.6.32 --with-__thread \
--with-binutils=${LJOS}/cross-tools/bin \
--with-headers=${LJOS}/usr/include \
--cache-file=config.cache
```

The error is like this

```
configure: loading cache config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... -gcc
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/noob/Desktop/glibc- build':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
```

[These](https://textuploader.com/1e7e4) are the contents on my config.log

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What's the output of `echo ${LJOS_TARGET}`?  I suspect it's empty.  How does it get set?

Comment: The output is blank.

Comment: I set it to 'export LJOS_TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' as per in the guide, but I'm getting the same error ; 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found'